# Responsive paragraphs using relative units

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

This the header of the page I'm working on I'm trying to use my Svg designs to be helpful to me while working in the page
`

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100"
      xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700;800;900&display=swap');
    .st0{fill:#F94151;}
    .st2{font-family: 'Montserrat Black'}
    .st3{position: absolute;top: 45%;left: 10%;font-size:3.5vw;}
    .st4{font-size:2.5vw;position:absolute;top: 60%;left: 10%;}
    .st5{font-family: 'Montserrat ExtraBold', 'Montserrat Medium'}
    
</style>
<rect x="1%" y="10%" class="st0" width="28.82" height="85.49"/>
<p id="year"  herf="*" class="st2 st3"> </p>
        <p class="st4 st5">SCHEDULES FOR STUDENTS</p>
<!--<text  href="*" x="5%" y="90%" class="st5 st4"  style="fill:black;">SCHEDULES FOR STUDENTS </text>  -->     
</svg>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't make it the usual way but i had to use @media only screen and  css style for both paragraphs and somehow it looks good now

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .st4{
    top: 35%;
     left: 10%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.st3{
    top: 20%;left: 10%;
  }
}
```